# Oracle Sql Developer I Can Not Edit

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

A record does not allow me to edit it. How can I edit the script by typing?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiJvo.png)

Comment: Please read [this article by @thatjeffsmith](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/06/sql-developer-im-looking-at-a-record-how-do-i-edit-it/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit a record form select statement because this statement is read only.

If you want to update the record you have tow options:

1. Update statement. 

   `UPDATE [TABLE_NAME]
   SET [COLUMN_NAME] = [VALUE]
   WHERE
   CONDITION1 AND CONDETION2;`
2. Select the table by click on it from table table at the left then click on data table from top of the table then filter to find the requested record then update the record and click on commit.